# Pricing of Binary or Digital Options or Feynman-Kac Equation for $\mathbb E f(X_T)$ with diffusion $X$ and discontinuous function $f$.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, stochastic-processes, stochastic-integrals, maximum-principle

I am trying to find references (books, papers, etc.) for calculating $\mathbb E f(X_T)$, where $X_T$ is a diffusion and  $f$ is a real function that is not continuous by means of solving a PDE or Feynman-Kac equation.

Thank you

Comment: I am not aware of a F-K version for discontinuous processes.  Try a special case (e.g., jump-diffusion component) and see if you can derive a PDE.  Merton's paper on JD might help.

Comment: Actually I am only interested in continuous processes. I edited the question...

Comment: So, how does one apply Ito's lemma if $f$ is discontinuous generally?

Comment: You don't apply it to $f$ but to $v(t,x)=\mathbb E^{t,x}(f(X_T))$. Which is regular enough under certain conditions to apply Ito's Lemma. To answer your question: There are versions for discontinuous convex functions or functions whose derivative is aboslutely continuous.